# Скриншот открывающегося окна

Tags: delphi

Пытаюсь сделать скриншот появляющейся второй формы над первой:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i: integer;
b: TBitmap;
begin
 Form2.Show;
 i := 1; // Устанавливаем счетчик
  b := TBitmap.Create(); // Создаем объект типа  TBitmap
  b.Width := Form2.ClientWidth; // Устанавливаем ширину изображения
  b.Height := Form2.ClientHeight; // Устанавливаем высоту изображения
  b.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), Form2.Canvas,
  Form2.ClientRect);    // Копируем канву формы в наш TBitmap
  while FileExists(InttoStr(i) + '.bmp') do       // Генерируем уникальное имя
  inc(i);
  b.SavetoFile(InttoStr(i) + '.bmp');             // Сохраняем картинку
  b.Free;
end;
```

На скриншоте второй формы не до конца прорисовываются компоненты (см. картинку).

Также пробовал делать sleep сразу после Form2.Show, но всю задержку я наблюдал непрорисованное окно Form2 - очень странно. я как-то думал, что после Form2.Show форма-то уже должна нарисоваться...

[image: пример]

Comment: Происходит так потому, что для прорисовки окну нужно обработать несколько сообщений от ОС. А пока ваш код не выполнится - сообщения не будут обрабатываться (Sleep - это тоже часть вашего кода). В качестве костыля - можно после Form2.Show поставить Application.ProcessMessages. В качестве более нормального решения - нужно сделать операции показа формы и снятия с нее скриншота разделенными по времени.

Comment: иными словами sleep прерывает ваш главный поток, который прорисовывает и саму эту форму. то есть профита от него не будет никакого. Оконные сообщения которые отправляются при открытии формы ставятся в очередь обработки, и некоторые выполняются уже после того, как ваш метод кнопки завершается. Можете попробовать делать скриншот при показе самой формы, а-ля в `OnShow()`

Comment: перенес в OnShow() - ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1):

Вот и [решение](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TWinControl_PaintTo@HDC@Integer@Integer.html):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  b: TBitmap;
begin
  Form2.Show;
  b := TBitmap.Create();
  b.Width := Form2.ClientWidth;
  b.Height := Form2.ClientHeight; 
  Form2.PaintTo(b.Canvas, 0, 0);
  b.SavetoFile('screen.bmp');
  b.Free;
end;
```

Comment: хах, я в мыслях не далек от этого варианта, но не додумался :) зы: вам бы try-finally блоки в код добавить не помешало